# Polymer non blocking asynchronous function that is linked to template

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, polymer

I have template

```
<core-list data="{{ list }}" height="80">
    <template>
        <app-list-item transaction="{{ transaction }}"></app-list-item>
    </template>
</core-list>
```

and js part that sets this.list data

```
# Polymer("app-list", {

ready: function() {
    this.list = null;
},
activeChanged: function(oldValue, isActive) {
    if (isActive == "1") {
        this.initialize();
    }
},
initialize: function() {
    var response = this.fetchListData();
    this.list = response.data;
}
```

I can trigger `initialize()` when template element is activated using [attributeChangedCallback()](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3apolymer-project.org%20attributeChangedCallback) (by click of the button)

I'm getting `this.list` data from external API using `XMLHttpRequest()` and this request takes time.

So when I'm pushing the button to activate my element application freezes for view seconds.

Is there a way to create some kind of callback method that will populate this.list only as soon as API data arrives? Until then this.list should stay as null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do this is with `<core-ajax>`:

```
<core-ajax auto url="http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json" handleAs="json" response="{{list}}"></core-ajax>
<core-list data="{{ list.feed.entry }}" height="80">
  <template>
    <div>{{title.$t}}</div>
  </template>
</core-list>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/nasibiqe/1/edit

The `auto` attribute tells core-ajax to make its request as soon as the element is ready. Then, we data bind core-list's `data` attribute to the ajax's `response` attribute. This only populates the list when data is available. If you instead want to make the XHR request when a button is pressed, remove the `auto` attr:

```
<core-ajax id="ajax" url="..." handleAs="json" response="{{list}}"></core-ajax>
<button on-click="{{go}}">Go</button>

go: function() {
  this.$.ajax.go();
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/giwujija/1/edit

Comment: Hi Eric, does polymer 1.0 already have an equivalent solution to this one?  Thanks!

Comment: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax is the 1.0 version of core-ajax. Should be able to do the same thing as this post, however syntax might have changed a bit. We're also still porting core-list.